# Migrating MVC4 problems in Url.Action with jquery params

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2, migration, url.action

I am migrating from MVC2 to MVC4 and I have a problem when I use the Url.Action function whith params from jquery. The generated url is wrong.
Im using C# with Framework 4.5.1
This is my code:

```
            var doc = jQuery('#grilla').jqGrid('getCell', row_id, 'Doc');
            var tipoDoc = jQuery('#grilla').jqGrid('getCell', row_id, 'TipoDoc');
            var idA = jQuery('#grilla').jqGrid('getCell', row_id, 'A');


            var subGrilla = jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                url: '<%= Url.Action("ObDCob", "ListCob",new { area = "Cob", xsDoc = "'+doc+'",xsTipoDoc = "'+tipoDoc+'",xiA = "'+idA+'"}) %>',
```

When the HTML is generated, the following is generated:

```
'/clearing/WebBP/Cob/ListCob/ObDCob/'%2bdoc%2b'/'%2btipoDoc%2b'/'%2bidA%2b''
```

Instead:

```
'/clearing/WebBP/Cob/ListCob/ObDCob/doc/tipoDoc/idA'
```

Any solution for this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In MVC 4 use @ instead of <%= for Url.Action()

```
 url: '@Url.Action("ObDCob", "ListCob",new { area = "Cob", xsDoc = "'+doc+'",xsTipoDoc = "'+tipoDoc+'",xiA = "'+idA+'"})'
```